# Jquery: How to find if element has inline property (not in CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

I have a tag such as:

```
<div class="menu" style="display:relative;">
```

..and I am trying to check with:

```
if ($('.menu').css('display','relative'))
```

.. the CSS for **.menu** has display:fixed; so it's ignoring the inline style and returning negative for if.

What's the best way to check the active style attribute on an element regardless if in CSS or inline?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not how you check the value; you're setting the `display` property as `relative` when you call `$('.menu').css('display', 'relative')`. Check the [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for the getter function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code you are setting `display` attribute with `relative`.
try this:

```
if ($('.menu').css('display') == 'relative'){
   //your code
}
```

The problem is that `display` hasn't attribute `relative`, maybe you mean `position` like this:

```
<div class="menu" style="position:relative;">
```

and jQuery:

```
if ($('.menu').css('position') == 'relative'){
       //your code
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Sorry about the typo i wrote Display instead of Position, the typo was here only.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `display:relative` in CSS. it is `position:relative`